# Powershell Invoke-Expression A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name = ""

Tags: powershell, invoke, invoke-command

Im trying to invoke a Ps script from antoher script. The scripts are both in the same path.
Also the script I'm trying to invoke takes 4 parameters.

Whem i execute that file from powershell with the parameters, then it works without errors.

But invoking it with the Invoke-Expression Command does not work.
Keep getting the error :

'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name'

Script with the Paramters :

```
        param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Samname,
        [string] $Fullname,
        [string] $Password,
        [string] $Groups
    )    

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force

New-localuser -name $Samname -FullName $Fullname -password $securePassword -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword

#Add the User to the Groups

$localGroups = Get-LocalGroup
[string[]]$GroupArray = $Groups.Split(' ')
    foreach ($localgroup in $localGroups){

        foreach ($group in $GroupArray){

            $group = $group.Replace(';', '') 
 
        if ($group.toString().Equals($localgroup.toString())){
            Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $localgroup -Member $samname
        }
    }
}
```

Script with Invoke-Expression command :

```
$XmlDocument = 'C:\SomeFile\toPs\TmpUser.config'
[XML]$XmlFile = Get-Content $XmlDocument

[string] $Samname = $XmlFile.User.Username
[string] $Fullname = $XmlFile.User.Fullname
[string] $Password = $XmlFile.User.Password
[string] $Groups = $XmlFile.User.Groups 

$script = ".\CreateUser.ps1" 

Invoke-Expression $script "-Samname $Samname -Fullname $Fullname -Password $Password -Groups $Groups"
```

I'm not that sure if I'm using the params the right way, when I invoke the script.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Expression` in the first place? Just do `& $script -Samname $Samname -Fullname $Fullname -Password $Password -Groups $Groups`

Comment: I don't know, i read it on google :') 
Now it works, thanks @MathiasR.Jessen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's tripping up `Invoke-Expression` without the full extent of the error message, but the good news is that **you don't need `Invoke-Expression` at all**!

Use [the invocation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) (also known as the "call operator", `&`) instead, it natively supports parameter binding:

```
$XmlDocument = 'C:\SomeFile\toPs\TmpUser.config'
[XML]$XmlFile = Get-Content $XmlDocument

[string] $Samname = $XmlFile.User.Username
[string] $Fullname = $XmlFile.User.Fullname
[string] $Password = $XmlFile.User.Password
[string] $Groups = $XmlFile.User.Groups 

$script = ".\CreateUser.ps1" 

& $script -Samname $Samname -Fullname $Fullname -Password $Password -Groups $Groups
```

Comment: Thx man, i didn't knowabout the invocation operator (&). 
I'm new to Powershell. Anway Big Thanks :)

Comment: @Subscaper Initial learning curve can be a bit steep, I suggest checking out the `about_*` help files in the documentation, specifically `about_Operators`, I've updated the answer with a link. Good luck on your PowerShell journey! :)

Comment: Thx mate, appreciate it :)